# modifying child object of list in kotlin but list is equal to not modifed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have a data class like this

```
data class TestModel(val id: Int, val sentence: String , var isPlaying: Boolean)
```

And I make a mutableList of that

```
val list: MutableList<TestModel> = arrayListOf(
    TestModel(1,"test",false),
    TestModel(2,"test2",false),
    TestModel(3,"test3",false))
```

then make a copy of the list in another object

```
val list2=list
```

when I modify list, for example:

```
list2[0].isPlaying=true
```

if I check the equality of these two lists

```
print(list==list2)
```

the result will be true while data in `list` is modified

I use this list in Android ListAdapter and while list is as same as old list, the adapter will not understand I have do some modifying.

How I can achieve what I want?
thanks for your response

Comment: Which property of class you want to check ? isPlaying only.

Comment: No, I want to check entire list. in fact my problem is not checking list. android list adapter does not accept same list when submitting new one while maybe one property of object has been changed . the problem is list1 is equal to list2 while list2 has an index that one of it's property is changed

Comment: here `val list2 = list` you copy the reference, not the list, and after `list2[0].isPlaying = true` the variable `list[0].isPlaying` will also be `true` because it is the same list (object). And adapter doesn't observe changes in your list, you should use `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @IR42  isn't there any way to accomplish this without manually `notiftdatasetchange()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you are modifying also the data classes of the original list. So if you print both lists you will get the same results:

> list: [TestModel(id=1, sentence=test, isPlaying=true), TestModel(id=2,
>   sentence=test2, isPlaying=false), TestModel(id=3, sentence=test3,
>   isPlaying=false)]
>
> list2: [TestModel(id=1, sentence=test, isPlaying=true), TestModel(id=2, sentence=test2, isPlaying=false), TestModel(id=3,
>   sentence=test3, isPlaying=false)]

You need to make a copy of each of the data classes to have the results that you want otherwise you will be referring to the same data classes of the original list and both will have the same data

For that, you can use this function if you want or something to make a copy of those data classes:

```
fun MutableList<TestModel>.copyOf(): MutableList<TestModel> {
    return this.map { it.copy() }.toMutableList()
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val list = mutableListOf(
    TestModel(1,"test",false),
    TestModel(2,"test2",false),
    TestModel(3,"test3",false)
)
val list2=list.copyOf()
list2[0].isPlaying=true
println(list==list2)
```

Hope this helps!